# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception issue when getting the data from database

Tags: java, android, database, exception

I am trying to get data from the db in the response object and showing it on the client side. But I am getting this array index out of bounds exception.I am sure I am doing it correct,but just cant make it run.
the error I get is

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1956; index=1956
at com.pda.kaizen.ConnectionImpl.getCustomers(ConnectionImpl.java:139)
at com.pda.kaizen.activity.MainMenuActivity$1.run(MainMenuActivity.java:123)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

this is the server side code

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("100|OK");
for (Customer customer : customers) {
    sb.append("|").append(customer.getId())
      .append("|").append(customer.getCode())
      .append("|").append(customer.getName())
      .append("|").append(customer.getNameFarsi())
      .append("|").append(customer.getAddress())
      .append("|").append(customer.getType())
      .append("|").append(customer.getPhoneNo())
      .append("|").append(customer.getMobileNo())
      .append("|").append(customer.getFaxNo())
      .append("|").append(customer.getEmail())
      .append("|").append(customer.getRegisterCode())
      .append("|").append(customer.getOrganizationName())
      .append("|").append(customer.getEconomicCode())
      .append("|").append(customer.getMelliCode())
      .append("|").append("-1".equals(customer.getPostCode())?"":customer.getPostCode())
      .append("|").append(customer.getFirstName())
      .append("|").append(customer.getLastName());
}
return sb.toString();
```

This is the Activity code

```
@Override
public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "customer"));
    try {
        String response = executeHttpPost(params);
        String[] result = response.split(DELIMITER);
        List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();

        for (int i = 2; i < result.length - 16; i += 17) {
            String id = result[i + 0];
            String code = result[i + 1];
            //String name = result[i + 2]; 
            String name = result[i + 3];
            String address = result[i + 4];
            String type = result[i + 5];
            String phone = result[i + 6];
            String mobile = result[i + 7];
            String fax = result[i+8];
            String email = result[i+9];
            String registerCode = result[i+10];
            String organizationName = result[i+11];
            String economicCode = result[i+12];
            String melliCode = result[i+13];
            String postCode = result[i+14];
            String firstName = result[i+15];
            String lastName = result[i+16];
            Customer customer = new Customer(id, code, name, address, type,phone,mobile,fax,email,registerCode,organizationName,economicCode,melliCode,postCode,firstName,lastName);
            customers.add(customer);
        }
        return customers;
    }
    catch (Exception exc) {
        Log.e("----", exc.getMessage(), exc);
        throw new ConnectionException(exc.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is customers an array or arraylist?

Comment: that is result? what it contains? how you are creating it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the framework you are using - but why does your loop start with `i=2` and not `i=0`?

Comment: @RonK he probably wants to skip "100|OK"

Comment: @RonK yes i want to skip 100|OK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be wrong - but I believe your problem is with how you `split` your string.

If you do this: `"a|b|c".split("\\|")` - you will get an array of 3 strings.
If you do this: `"a||".split("\\|")` - you will get an array of **1** string.

This is because `split` trims out the end.

Assuming you are using `split` - check your data and see if the last customer has a **last name**. 
If no - then I am correct.

See the following ideone code as a sample:
[Example of code failing due to empty data](http://ideone.com/o9wmj)

To solve the problem, you should introduce spaces between delimiters (or any other value you wish) to ensure `split` takes them into account.

See the following ideone code as an example:
[Example of code running with spaces between delimiters.](http://ideone.com/o9wmj)

NOTE: Quote from the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
>   This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with
>   the given expression and a limit argument of zero. **Trailing empty
>   strings are therefore not included** in the resulting array.

Comment: **check your data and see if the last customer has a last name.**
you were absolute correct!!.This was an eye opener for me regarding split thingy and the spaces

Answer (score 2):

arrays are zero indexed in java so for an array of length=1956 the max index used should be `myArray[1955]` . And of course the first element is `myArray[0]`

Answer (score 2):

your for loop exit condition is wrong, when you get `result[i+16]` you should be sure that `i < result.length - 16`

```
for (int i = 2; i < result.length-16; i += 17) {
```

Comment: it worked with your suggestion but i did not understand why i need to substract 16. can you please explain more

Comment: I suspect this will lose the last customer. I fully expect this to be a problem with `result`, but unfortunately we haven't been shown the code which creates the array.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct - please check my answer before you continue http://stackoverflow.com/a/12687427/357360

Comment: assume in for loop `i=36`(34+2) and your array length is 52, when you get `result[i+16]` your `i+16` equals to array length, and you get `arrayIndexOutOfBound` because array indexing start with `0` and max index is `length-1`. i think with my suggestion you lose last customer, why you initialize i with `2` and not `1`?

Comment: yes infact i checked the data and it is skipping the last data

Comment: @ZAJ: And have you used a debugger to work out what the result actually looks like? Basically it *looks* like you should get n * 17 + 2 results, but a length of 1956 suggests that's not the case. Either you're missing the very last entry (as per RonK's answer) or something else is going on. We can't work that out for you.

Comment: @ZAJ what is `DELIMITER` value?

Comment: @Farnabaz private static final String DELIMITER = "\\|";

Answer (score 1):

> I am sure i am doing it correct

I'm pretty sure you're not... generally speaking, if something's not behaving as you'd expect it to, you should start off with the assumption that you're *not* doing everything correctly.

I strongly suspect this is the problem:

```
for (int i = 2; i < result.length; i += 17)
```

If the failure is at index 1956, I suspect the problem is that there are exactly 1956 elements, representing 115 entries *starting at index 1*.

So try:

```
for (int i = 1; i < result.length; i += 17)
```

Now given your initial `"100|OK"`, I can see *why* you'd expect to start at index 2, but it appears that's not the case. It doesn't help that you haven't shown us how you're getting `result` - maybe that's already "swallowing" one value?

You should really look at your results in the debugger to investigate the suspicious offset.

Comment: if i start with 1 then it iwll include that OK, which i dont wnat to

Comment: @ZAJ: Have you debugged into `result` to check that? I *strongly* suspect that your data isn't what you think it is.

Comment: `List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);`
    `params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "customer"));`
       `try {`
                      `String response = executeHttpPost(params);`
  ` String[] result = response.split(DELIMITER);
 `  List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();

Comment: @ZAJ And what value is *actually* getting assigned to `response` when you call `executeHttpPost(params)`. Not what value do you *think* is getting assigned, or what *should* be assigned, but if you run the *actual* code in a debugger, you can look at what has *actually* been assigned. Once you've looked at this you will probably be able to understand why your loop is going out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

analyse the exception carefully.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1956; index=1956
```

it says the length is 1956 and the index is 1956. if your length of an array is 1956, the last index shoyuld be 1955. array indexes start with zero.

Comment: what do you mean.can you please elaborate

Comment: @ZAJ arrays are zero indexed. if you have an array of 4 elements, its length would be 4, but uif you wanna access the 4th element in the array you aaccess it like arr[3].